# Unbind Events with JQuery: Does it work with events setup in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few onclick and on mouseover events in my html generated by PHP, something like this:

```
<div onmouseover="fave('heart_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>';" class="heart"><a href=""></a></div>
```

I wish to make use of unbind on the mouseover but it hasn't worked when I tried this:

```
$('#'+ id).unbind('mouseover');
```

So I am guessing unbind will only work with events created by JQuery? Is there something else I can try?

Btw, I can't move my events to a separate js file as each id is unique.

Thanks all

Comment: But your `<div>` doesn't have an `id`.

Comment: @Kenny - the id in the second part is related to another element. I have removed certain things to simplify my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not. `unbind` will *not* remove events registered through the [inline model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html). Any [event registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) events you create (bound to the same element) will overwrite your inline code, but still, `unbind` will leave those intact. In other words, yes, unbind will only unbind event handlers bound to the element using jQuery.

See for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/ktLTL/